# How to specify the dockerfile path in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

I have created a pipeline in azuredevops for .NET project.
My .sln file and docker file are present in different git repos.

How can I specify the dockerfile path in my azurepipeline.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `.sln file` and `docker file` are in different git repos, you need to check out two git repos in Yaml file.

If your two git repos are in the same organization, you could directly add `check out step`  in Steps.

For example:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: git://Test Project/Docker Repo@master
```

**Explaination:**

The first checkout step is used to check out the repo where the yaml file is located (e.g. sln repo).

The second checkout step is used to checkout another repo(e.g. dockerfile repo).

Then two Repos will be downloaded  to the `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` (C:\agent_work\1\s)

[image]

So the dockerfile path could be `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\RepoName\...\Dockerfile`.

If two git repos are in different resource (e.g. github , other organizaitons) , you need to add repo resource and checkout the repo.

Here is the doc about [Use multiple repositories in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops).